# Ember.js - DynamicTemplate depending on Model

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

I would like to create an application which will create dynamically a grid to display informations according to an xml file. Each pages will be define on this xml.

Exemple :

```
<page name="index">
  <component>
    <content_type>html</content_type>
    <posx>1</posx>
    <posy>1</posy>
    <content></content>
  </component>
  <component>
    <content_type>html</content_type>
    <posx>1</posx>
    <posy>2</posy>
    <content></content>
  </component>
</page>
```

In this exemple, a page Index with a row and 2 cols will be created.

I would like to know how you think is the best way to create this application in ember V 1.0? 
Is-it possible to use a page as a model and create the template dynamically with Ember.view :

```
Index.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  // My code
});
```

I found a way to do that, but I'm not sure it is a clean way that is why I am asking.
I'm learning how to use ember.js at the moment, please be understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably create some sort of parser, then dynamically create views and inject them into the page.  This is an interesting problem, I might not use Ember for it, It seems like you are constrained to some interesting requirements.  It feels a bit like using a hammer for a screw, you might be stuck fighting Ember (or any framework) more than gaining from it.  Just my opinion based off this tidbit of info

Comment: Thanks for this feedback.
I'm sharing your opinion but I'm sure there is a way with ember or angular, just need to find it ^^
I know I don't give enough informations but I do it to don't push you in my way to do it.

could you just give me your way to create views dynamically ?